# makefile aliases

Tags: makefile

Please explain  $@ $^ $ in the makefile below

```
LIBS  = -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32
CFLAGS = -Wall

# (This should be the actual list of C files)
SRC=$(wildcard '*.c')

test: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Answer (score 8):

This is what these two symbols mean:

- $@ is the target i.e. `test`
- $^ is the list of pre-requisites for the rule (which in this case is the expanded wild card list as specified in `SRC=$(wildcard '*.c')`)

All such variables are explained in the [Automatic variables page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) of the GNU make manual.

Comment: What does 'expands the wildcard list as specified in `SRC=$(wildcard '*.c')`' mean? does it just result in `'*.c'`?

Comment: Ah, it's a [file matching wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function).

Comment: @naught101 It is stated explicitly in the answer *wild card list*, think of a shell glob for wildcards... :)

Comment: Yeah. For a noob, it's pretty confusing, because a plain wildcard string works for depndencies (e.g. `*.c`, instead of `$(wildcard '*.c')`), but not in variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SRC=$(wildcard '*.c')
```

This just all your source file name ending with .c ie file1.c, file2.c file3.c etc.

in

```
test: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

$ is a way to define variables in Makefile

$@  is your target, in your case it is "test".

$^  is the list of all the prerequisites of the rule, including the names of the directories in which they were found

$< is the list of all dependencies

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables