# make does not detect changes in source files

Tags: makefile

I have the following project structure:

```
ProjectDir
|           
+---CurrentDir
|       Makefile
|       
+---App1
|   |   Source1.cs
|   |   Source2.cs
|   |   
|
\---App2
    |   Source1.cs
    |   Source2.cs
    |
```

and I want to build all applications in the `CurrentDir`. The Makefile is as follows:

```
APPS=App1.exe App2.exe

all: $(APPS)

$(APPS) : %.exe : $(wildcard ../%/*.cs) 
    csc /nologo /out:$@ ..\\$(basename $@)\\*.cs
```

The applications build without any problems, but whenever I change something in one of the source files, make does not rebuild the binaries (Nothing to be done for 'all').

Why is that and how can I fix this? I guess it has something to do with the wildcard expression.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170467/makefiles-compile-all-c-files-at-once. Just change the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(wildcard)` function is being evaluated at make parse time (when `%` isn't special) and is trying to glob `../%/*.cs` which, naturally, isn't matching anything. To do what you want as you've written it you need to use [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(APPS) : %.exe : $$(wildcard ../$$*/*.cs)
```

That being said doing this in stanges more manually might be more useful (but would require more rewriting of your makefile).